# How to trigger the "Save As" dialog in Internet Explorer from an angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have an angularjs controller that retrieves a URL from a rest endpoint. The response contains the URL of a text file on S3, and populates the src attribute of a hidden iframe with the contents of that file.

Template

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.getUrl()" class="btn btn-default"></button>
    <iframe ng-hide="true" ng-src="{{myCtrl.s3Link}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
  });

function MyController($http, $sce) {
  var vm = this;
  var savedState = browserBackService.retrieveState('resultsPage');
  vm.getUrl = getUrl;
  vm.s3Link = '';

  function getUrl() {
    vm.extractDownloadLink = '';
    $http.get('/api/getS3url').then(extractSuccessCallback);
  }

  function extractSuccessCallback(response) {
    vm.extractDownloadLink = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response.data.url);
  }
}
```

Rest Response

```
{
  "url":"https://myaws.aws.net/s3_bucket/1/2/myFile.txt"
}
```

The file exists, and the path is correct. In Chrome and Firefox, this triggers a "Save As" dialog box, which is the correct behaviour, but on Internet Explorer 10, and Edge, nothing happens.

What changes are needed to allow this to complete successfully in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a library that handles many browsers such as `angular-file-saver`

[Angular File Saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver)

Answer (score 0):

Can't not reproduce the problem using your code, I suppose perhaps you are using the URL.createObjectURL() method or the a tag download property to download file, or similar like this. And they don't support IE browser.

In my opinion, I suggest you could try to modify the API, and add a method to get the file blob data. Then, in the IE and Edge browser, after getting the file data, you could use the msSaveOrOpenBlob method to download the file in IE and Edge browser, and in the Chrome or Firefox browser, you could create a hyperlink to download the file using the URL. More detail information, please check [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bamossza/gbrhqgdd/7/):

```
        function btnAttachFileDownload() {

            let fileUpload = $('input#fileUpload');
            let fileName = fileUpload[0].files[0].name;
            let fileSize = fileUpload[0].files[0].size;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload[0].files[0]);
            reader.onload = function () {
                var blob = b64toBlob(reader.result);
                if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    console.log('IE 11');
                    // IE 11 the legacy version of Microsoft Edge
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
                } else {
                    console.log('Google chome, Firefox, ....');
                    // Google chome, Firefox, ....
                    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
                    $('#filedownload').attr('download', fileName);
                    $('#filedownload').attr('href', url);
                    $('#filedownload')[0].click();
                }
            };
            reader.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            };
        };
```